# Find out if the OS is running in a virtual environment

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, system-installation, vmware

Is there any way to find out if the OS I'm running (actually installing) is running in a VMWare machine. I need to disable `ntp` settings if the automated install is done on a virtual machine but keep them enabled if installing on bare metal.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. The linked question asks how to determine *which* virtualization technology is used, which is much more difficult and less reliable (per the answers given!) and arguably less useful than merely determining *whether* the machine is virtual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `dmidecode` or `lshw` and `grep`ing seems to be to be the best way to find out.

Comment: grep for what? I ran `sudo dmidecode | grep hyper` and `sudo dmidecode | grep virt` but none of them works. `lshw`'s result is exactly the same as `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc See the linked duplicate question, which explains how to use these functions to find *specific* virtualization info.

Answer (score 87):

Linux adds the `hypervisor` flag to `/proc/cpuinfo` if the kernel detects running on some sort of a hypervisor.

Comment: This is the most reliable way and should be the accepted answer IMHO.  One can therefore use this command: `grep -q ^flags.*\ hypervisor\  /proc/cpuinfo && echo "This machine is a VM"`

Comment: @dr01 - This only worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04LTS if I removed the backslash after hypervisor. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: You're right, there should be two spaces after that backslash. This also works: `grep -q ^flags.*\ hypervisor /proc/cpuinfo && echo "This machine is a VM"` This reads `/proc/cpuinfo` and checks if the `flags:` line contains the string `hypervisor`, as suggested by Jan.

Comment: This won't work on RH 5.x (though the the flag is present in RH6.x and above)

Comment: This won't work on virtualbox

Comment: I like this one, as it can be used in C programs (no external dependency).

Comment: This doesn't work in nspawn either.

Answer (score 33):

On Linux you can use the command `virt-what`

```
[root@myhost]# virt-what
vmware
```

Example Output for a linux on Windows **HyperV**

```
[root@linuxvm11~] # virt-what
hyperv
```

Example Output for centos8 on **vmware**

```
CentOS:root@box003:~/CM/bin/tools# virt-what
vmware
```

Comment: This did not work for me in an unprivileged docker container.  It hits a `permission denied` error reading `/proc/1/environ`, **as root**!

Answer (score 22):

This worked better for me as it gives me specific information about the manufacturer and the product name.

```
dmidecode -t system|grep 'Manufacturer\|Product'
```

Output on Dell server:

```
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: PowerEdge C5220
```

Output on Virtualbox VM:

```
Manufacturer: innotek GmbH
Product Name: VirtualBox
```

Output on KVM/QEMU:

```
Manufacturer: QEMU
Product Name: Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
```

This is great for scripts that can parse these out for better identification of servers... but if you use Chef in your infrastructure, you can check the node attribute `Virtualization -> system` in the chef server .

Comment: on openstack: ''' Manufacturer: OpenStack Foundation
 Product Name: OpenStack Nova
'''

Comment: on vmware ''' Manufacturer: VMware, Inc.
 Product Name: VMware Virtual Platform
'''

Answer (score 14):

Run:

```
$ dmesg |grep -i hypervisor
Hypervisor detected: KVM
```

Answer (score 3):

The best idea would probably to look at the hardware. At least with VirtualBox you can easily determine that you are on a virtual machine, due to the names of some of the hardware devices (for example `/sys/block/sda/device/model` will say "VBOX HARDDISK").

Since all your machines are VMware, just pick one of those things and check that.

Comment: that will work if i'm only using virtual harddrives.

Comment: The Harddisk was just an example, check for other devices, maybe the harddisk controller or the graphics card (I don't have vmware here so I cannot check)

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is a way to tell whether the OS/host is a virtualized host or not, just you have a perl module Sys::Detect::Virtualization and the script with it `virtdetect`. It does all the possible heuristics/guess detections and reports the detected OS environment.  Give it a try.

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Sys-Detect-Virtualization/script/virtdetect

Answer (score 3):

You could try Joanna Rutkowska's [Red Pill](http://www.ouah.org/Red_%20Pill.html)  This little program examines the IDTR (interrupt descriptor table register) using the [`SIDT`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/sidt.htm) instruction (x86 only), which apparently will be set differently by different VMMs.

Comment: The link to the source code is broken :/

Answer (score 2):

I have done it:

```
hypervisor=`dmesg --notime | grep -i hypervisor | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -d " \t\n\r"`
echo "Hypervisor is $hypervisor"
```

It helps on scripts

Answer (score 2):

All of these answers work in some cases but not others.

For example, you can depend on `dmesg` while boot-up log details are still in the ring buffer, but it will likely fail on a machine that has been running for any length of time.  Worse, a message might be logged by the bare metal OS concerning a running hypervisor, in which case a naive test like `dmesg | grep -i vmware` will return a false positive.

Testing under Docker is quite different. Docker has no `/proc/cpuinfo` of its own; instead it passes on the host machine's info. Meanwhile, `dmidecode` fails trying to read a directory `/dev/mem` not seen by Docker.

`virt-what` has detection for Docker containers, but needs to be patched to cope with a recent change in container privileges.  It crashes trying to access `/proc/1/environ` before it reaches the tests for Docker.

It is important to pay attention to the `virt-what` caveat emptor :

> Most of the time, using this program is the wrong thing to do. Instead
>   you should detect the specific features you actually want to use.

In my case, publishing a tutorial that installs a **ton** of crap users may not want after all, I refuse to let it run on bare metal, with this test :

```
[[ 0 < $(grep -c docker /proc/1/cgroup) ]] || [[ "X$(sudo virt-what)X" != "XX" ]] && export VIRTUALIZED=true;
```

**Note** : I realize the OP asks specifically about VMWare in the body of the question, but the title of the question will attract many readers (like me) looking for the more general case.

Comment: Docker is *not* a virtualization in the classical sense. It is a container, the processes still run inside the same kernel. Thus your answer, while it might be correct, is outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you jump in quickly and correct Wikipedia's misunderstanding :  "Docker is an open-source project that automates the deployment of applications inside software containers, by providing an additional layer of abstraction and automation of operating-system-level virtualization on Linux."

Comment: There are a lot of half-truth and easy to misunderstand things written on wikipedia. Do not use it to prove a point and take everything written there with a grain of salt. Also not that "virtualization" is broader term then what we are discussing here. That is why I wrote "in the classical sense" above. Just accept that a docker container is pretty different from a virtual machine (which is the whole point of docker in the first place by the way).

Comment: I don't need Wikipedia to prove my point.  I made a YouTube video [Meteor / CircleCI Tutorial -- #0 Create a Docker Machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzA3ddE0XPA) that explains how to start my Docker image [xubuntu-x2go-phusion](https://hub.docker.com/r/warehouseman/xubuntu-x2go-phusion/) of Xubuntu and X2Go with full GUI.  If I install Java in that machine it does not also get installed in the base OS.  Please, watch the video and then clarify for us my "wrong assumptions" that it's a virtual machine.

Comment: " If I install Java in that machine it does not also get installed in the base OS" that has nothing to do with this discussion. Surely it is not installed in the base OS (as the container has a separate file system). But that does not make a Docker container the same as a virtual machine. I am trying to clarify your wrong assumptions right now, but you do not seem overly interested in listing and understand what I am telling you.

Comment: Also the title "create a Docker **Machine**" is misleading, you create a Docker container, not a Docker machine. The docker image has a separate file system, but processes you start run on the host kernel. You do not run a separate kernel, like a traditional virtual machine. That is why the hypervisor flag is not set, you are not running inside a hypervisor after all. Just do not call other people's answer "inadequate" if you confuse things and make false assumptions.

Comment: The simple fact is, the OP wants ```ntp``` adjustments on bare metal **only**.  For that purpose, his code, running under Docker, is not on bare metal, so ```ntp``` should not (in fact, cannot) be enabled. Pointless hair-splitting about arbitrary "classical" definitions notwithstanding, your test is adequate for VMware but inadequate for anyone concerned about the more general case (which brought me to this thread in the first place).

Comment: No, it is not more general, but more two specific cases. One is running inside a container, the other is about running inside a virtual machine. You started the discussion by discrediting a perfectly valid answer as "inadequate", because it does not fit your point of view. You started introducing Docker into a topic that was not not concerned about that. Also my answer is still adequate and fully correct. Docker is simply no hypervisor, but most virtual machines are.

Comment: Your assumption : If it is not 100% virtual; it's bare metal.  My assumption : If it is not 100% bare metal; it's virtual.  In a world where millions of "classical" virtual machines are being dumped in favour of containers (and probably further innovations and variations on virtualization), building your assumption into software is not inadequate -- it's flat out -- wrong!

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. I never said it is bare metal. All I said is that containers like Docker are different from virtual machines. And my answer was fully correct, as it only applies to virtual machines. You extended the scope of the question yourself and then called my answer "inadequate", because it applied to the scope of the original question and not your extension. I just pointed out to you, that you have to treat containers like Docker differently from virtual machines, but calling my answer "inadequate" is wrong to begin with, since you base it on your subjective assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

Requires APIC, returns 0 if virtual machine, 1 if physical computer:

```
grep -q VBOX /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/APIC
```

Answer (score 1):

well, the most intuitive way I always do is:

> $ dmesg | grep -i vmware

Comment: nice - this works on virtual box: `dmesg | grep -i vbox`  - `ACPI: RSDP 000e0000 00024 (v02 VBOX  )`