# Easy way to determine the virtualization technology of a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, command-line, virtual-machine

I have command line access to a Linux machine which may or may not be virtualized. I want to determine what kind of virtualization technology it runs on, if any (VMWare, VirtualBox, KVM, OpenVZ, Xen, ). This isn't a hostile environment: I'm not trying to work against a VM that is trying to disguise itself, I'm diagnosing a flaky server that I know little about.

More precisely, I'm helping someone diagnose the issue, I'm not sitting at the helm. So I have to convey instructions like “copy-paste this command” and not “poke around `/proc` somewhere”. Ideally, it would be something like `lshw`: an easily-installable (if not preinstalled) command that does the poking around and prints out relevant information.

What's the easiest way of determining what virtualization technology this system may be a guest of? I'd appreciate if proposals mentioned which technologies (including bare hardware) can be conclusively detected and which can be conclusively eliminated. I'm mostly interested in Linux, but if it also works for other unices that's nice.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/425878/how-to-tell-if-i-am-on-a-xen-or-kvm-server | https://serverfault.com/questions/179105/how-to-find-out-if-running-inside-kvm-guest

Answer (score 141, accepted):

### `dmidecode -s system-product-name`

I have tested on Vmware Workstation, VirtualBox, QEMU with KVM, standalone QEMU with Ubuntu as the guest OS. Others have added additional platforms that they're familiar with as well.

#### Virtualization technologies

- VMware Workstation

  ```
  root@router:~# dmidecode -s system-product-name
  VMware Virtual Platform
  ```
- VirtualBox

  ```
  root@router:~# dmidecode -s system-product-name
  VirtualBox
  ```
- Qemu with KVM

  ```
  root@router:~# dmidecode -s system-product-name
  KVM
  ```
- Qemu (emulated)

  ```
  root@router:~# dmidecode -s system-product-name
  Bochs
  ```
- Microsoft VirtualPC

  ```
  root@router:~# dmidecode | egrep -i 'manufacturer|product'
  Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
  Product Name: Virtual Machine
  ```
- Virtuozzo

  ```
  root@router:~# dmidecode
  /dev/mem: Permission denied
  ```
- Xen

  ```
  root@router:~# dmidecode | grep -i domU
  Product Name: HVM domU
  ```

On bare metal, this returns an identification of the computer or motherboard model.

### `/dev/disk/by-id`

If you don't have the rights to run `dmidecode` then you can use:

Virtualization Technology: QEMU

```
ls -1 /dev/disk/by-id/
```

**Output**

```
[root@host-7-129 ~]# ls -1 /dev/disk/by-id/
ata-QEMU_DVD-ROM_QM00003
ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00001
ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00001-part1
ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00002
ata-QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00002-part1
scsi-SATA_QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00001
scsi-SATA_QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00001-part1
scsi-SATA_QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00002
scsi-SATA_QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00002-part1
```

#### References

- [How to detect virtualization at dmo.ca](http://www.dmo.ca/blog/detecting-virtualization-on-linux/)

Comment: Hyper-V returns a nearly worthless `Virtual Machine` for `dmidecode -s system-product-name`. There is nothing obvious under /dev/disk/by-id either.  facter appears to detect hyperv by looking at the lspci output.

Comment: Open VZ check for  `/proc/user_beancounters`

Comment: +1 for `/proc/user_beancounters` over OpenVZ wich is likely on cheap VPS's as example.

Comment: Both `dmidecode` and `/dev/disk/by-id` solutions fail in a Docker container. See unix.stackexchange.com/a/257207/106572

Comment: with qemu 2.5.0 (at least), `dmidecode -s system-product-name` returns a generic hardware description instead of the "KVM" or "Bochs" shown above. For me, this string is `Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)`.  `dmidecode -s system-manufacturer` returns the far less generic string `QEMU`. Since qemu allows DMI data to be provided, I suspect dmidecode is relatively easy to fool - no matter the field being read.

Comment: As said [further in this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120993/111755), `virt-what` is nice and since it's a shell script you can easily read the source to find which way is the best for detecting a particular virtualization system.

Comment: I've got `vServer` value from `dmidecode ` command on Hetzner servers.

Comment: @Mark I reproduce the failure this Ubuntu 18.04 on Ubuntu 18.04 setup: https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1046792/15 , it just output: `Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX , 1996)`.

Comment: Valid only on x86 based systems

Answer (score 61):

If the container is running `systemd`:

```
$ systemd-detect-virt
lxc
```

On KVM for example it returns:

```
kvm
```

and on a non-virtualized host:

```
none
```

See also:

- [systemd-detect-virt(1)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-detect-virt.html)
- [Detecting Virtualization](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/detect-virt.html)

Comment: This works for openvz as well.

Comment: It output `kvm` for Google Compute Engine, which is what I was trying to figure out. Thanks!

Comment: Simple command that works like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04! Much thanks :)

Comment: if you just want to know if you are on a vm or not using `systemd-detect-virt`, you can use the exit codes. 0 for VM, 1 for "bare metal"

Comment: What if it returns "qemu"? Does it mean KVM is used?

Answer (score 29):

### Desirable method

#### lshw

This command produces the following output on vairous VM technology guests.

```
$ sudo lshw -class system
```

#### Output

- KVM

  ```
  mungr                     
      description: Computer
      product: KVM
      vendor: Red Hat
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall64 vsyscall32
  ```
- Virtual Box

  ```
  fedora17                  
      description: Computer
      product: VirtualBox ()
      vendor: innotek GmbH
      version: 1.2
      serial: 0
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 vsyscall32
  ```
- VMWare

  ```
  partedmagic
      description: Computer
      product: VMware Virtual Platform ()
      vendor: VMware, Inc.
      version: None
      serial: VMware-56 4d 94 a0 53 e3 f3 c6-f9 a6 eb 1a 89 70 04 57
      width: 32 bits
      capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 smp-1.4 smp
  ```

### Scripting

If you're on Ubuntu/Debian there's the package `open-vm-tools` can be installed. It provides [`vmware-checkvm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/vmware-checkvm.1.html). It returns only a a digit. A `0` means it's a VM, a `1` means it's a physical system.

### Less desirable methods

If it's KVM the `/proc/scsi/scsi` and `ethtool` options show up as follows:

#### SCSI

```
$ cat /proc/scsi/scsi 
Attached devices:
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: QEMU     Model: QEMU DVD-ROM     Rev: 0.9.
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

#### ethtool

```
$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: virtio_net
version: 
firmware-version: 
bus-info: virtio0
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

The virtio_net is part of KVM. The `/proc/scsi/scsi` tells you that you're in a VM, and that you're most likely KVM.

#### dmesg

Using the following commands `grep`'ing through `dmesg` log.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i virtual
```

- VMWare

  ```
  VMware vmxnet virtual NIC driver
   Vendor: VMware    Model: Virtual disk      Rev: 1.0 
  hda: VMware Virtual IDE CDROM Drive, ATAPI CD/DVD-ROM drive
  ```
- QEmu or KVM

  If the `"-cpu host"` option has not been used, QEmu and KVM will identify themselves as:

  ```
  CPU: AMD QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1 stepping 03
  ```

  otherwise, the host's CPU information will be used both in `dmesg`, or in `/proc/cpuinfo`. However, you should see something like:

  ```
  [    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
  ```

  In newer kernels that understand that they're running under paravirtualization.
- Microsoft VirtualPC

  ```
  hda: Virtual HD, ATA DISK drive
  hdc: Virtual CD, ATAPI CD/DVD-ROM drive
  ```
- Xen

  ```
  $ sudo dmesg | grep -i xen
  Xen virtual console successfully installed as tty1
  ```
- Virtuozzo

  ```
  # method #1
  $ sudo dmesg
  (returns no output)

  # method #2
  $ sudo cat /var/log/dmesg
  (returns no output)

  # method #3
  $ sudo ls -al /proc/vz
  veinfo  veinfo_redir  veredir  vestat  vzaquota  vzdata
  ```

#### References

- [dmo.ca/ blog/ How to detect virtualization](http://www.dmo.ca/blog/detecting-virtualization-on-linux/)

Comment: That kind of poking around drivers is what I hoped to avoid: it'll be different for every VM technology and dependent on the settings. The product name reported by `lshw -class system` and `dmidecode` is exactly what I was hoping to find.

Comment: @Gilles - yeah I didn't mean for you to actual use them, only to capture the methods. I'm bringing up a Virtual Box and VMWare instances now to confirm the `lshw` output as well for those platforms. Give me a couple of minutes and I'll update the A.

Comment: @Gilles - looks like lshw can do the job as well for all the technologies. I've moved the answers to the bottom of the answer that weren't what you were looking so that others won't have to skip past them.

Comment: dmesg fills a fixed size ring buffer with all kinds of stuff.  It is completely inappropriate for this task. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257207/106572

Comment: @Martin - and that's why it's in the less desirable section of my answer. I typically write answers that are all inclusive, showing a variety of methods.

Comment: @sim  Yes. Obviously.  I was merely adding the (missing) clarification as to **why** it's less desirable, and why it may seem valid at first when in the long term it can be badly wrong..

Answer (score 16):

The [`virt-what` script](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) seems to cover most cases well...

I *do* like the disclaimer from the authors:

*Most of the time, using this program is the wrong thing to do. Instead you should detect the **specific** features you actually want to use.*

It's appeared on my EL5 and EL6 systems for the past few years as part of default installations. Ubuntu has it, and the source is available as well.

The *facts* detected by the script are [listed here](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/virt-what.txt), but can easily be extended for edge cases.

Comment: Link? Which systems does it recognize?

Comment: @Gilles Edited: But the script generally detects KVM, Xen, QEMU, VirtualBox, Parallels, OpenVZ, IBM System Z, LPAR, z/VM, Hitachi Virtage, VMWare, Microsoft Hyper-V. Hmm... should LXC be included?

Comment: LXC is included now.

Comment: As of January 2016, it fails with Docker.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257207/106572

Answer (score 16):

`hostnamectl` is your friend (requires *`systemd`*).

A few examples:

**Laptop without any virtualization**

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: earth.gangs.net
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 18a0752e1ccbeef09da51ad17fab1f1b
           Boot ID: beefdc99969e4a4a8525ff842b383c62
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-66-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

**Xen**

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: pluto.gangs.net
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: beef39aebbf8ba220ed0438b54497609
           Boot ID: beefc71e97ed48dbb436a470fe1920e1
    Virtualization: xen
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

**OpenVZ**

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: mars.gangs.net
         Icon name: computer-container
           Chassis: container
        Machine ID: 55296cb0566a4aaca10b8e3a4b28beef
           Boot ID: 1bb259b0eb064d9eb8a22d112211beef
    Virtualization: openvz
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 2.6.32-042stab120.16
      Architecture: x86-64
```

**KVM**

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: mercury.gangs.net
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: beeffefc50ae499881b024c25895ec86
           Boot ID: beef9c7662a240b3b3b04cef3d1518f0
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: how does the OS determine if it is running inside a virtual machine? it shouldn't, I have installed a very basic debian from command line and hostnamectl shows `Virtualization: oracle` regardless I have not installed any paravirtualization | Virtualbox guest additions

Answer (score 13):

```
isVMware() { [[ $(dmidecode -s system-manufacturer) = 'VMware, Inc.' ]]; }
isXen   () { [[ $(dmidecode -s system-manufacturer) = 'Xen'          ]]; }
isKVM   () { [[ $(dmidecode -s system-product-name) = 'KVM'          ]]; }
isVBox  () { [[ $(dmidecode -s system-product-name) = 'VirtualBox'   ]]; }
isVM    () { isVMware || isXen || isKVM || isVBox; }
```

Those are the tests we use at my company.

Answer (score 9):

If you get the person you're helping to install `facter`, you can do

```
facter virtual
```

No root access needed.

Debian Guest on Debian host:

```
[user@guest]$ facter virtual
virtualbox
```

I can't vouch for how well this would work with Xen/KVM/Qemu...

Answer (score 7):

In "recent" linux kernels, the kernel detects the hypervisor for you and prints a message that is easily available with `dmesg`.  This will tell you simply:

```
dmesg | grep "Hypervisor detected"
```

For example:

```
$ dmesg | grep "Hypervisor detected"
Hypervisor detected: VMware
```

As for what "recent" means, I am unclear which kernel version it was officially released in, but the commit that introduced this feature in the code base was on May 7, 2010.  See [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e08cae4181af9483b04ecfac48f01c8e5a5f27bf/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/hypervisor.c#L49).

Comment: `dmesg` fills a fixed size ring buffer with all kinds of stuff.  It is completely inappropriate for this task. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257207/106572

Answer (score 6):

### systemd-detect-virt

This will detect the type of virtualization technology used, and output it.

```
systemd-detect-virt
```

### Distinguishing between machine virtualization and container virtualization

Use the `--container` and `--vm` options to limit the type of virtualization that is detected.

### Exit codes

If you just want to know if virtualization is detected or not, without the specifics, then it's easier to check the exit code. It will return exit code 0 if virtualization is detected, and non-zero otherwise.

---

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it's tricky :)

```
root@server:~# dmidecode -s system-product-name
Bochs

root@server:~# dmidecode | egrep -i 'manufacturer|product|vendor'
        Vendor: Bochs
        Manufacturer: Bochs
        Product Name: Bochs
        Manufacturer: Bochs
        Manufacturer: Bochs
        Manufacturer: Bochs
        Manufacturer: Bochs
        Manufacturer: Bochs

root@server:~# virt-what
root@server:~# dpkg -l |grep virt-what
ii  virt-what                           1.2-1                        detect if we are running in a virtual machine

root@server:~# egrep -i 'virtual|vbox' /var/log/dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
[    0.385701] input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input0
```

Answer (score 3):

For VirtualBox, you could `lspci | grep -i virtualbox`, that gives:

```
$ lspci | grep -i virtualbox
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
```

Alternatively, `dmidecode -s system-product-name` (as @Rahul Patil suggests) is even more direct to the point (but needs root):

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
VirtualBox
```

For non-KVM QEMU, `dmidecode -s system-product-name` confusingly returns Bochs, but `dmesg | grep -i qemu` works (the storage devices that QEMU emulates usually have the name `QEMU HARDDISK`, `QEMU DVD-ROM` etc...).

Answer (score 3):

I usually use `lscpu` from the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package. It reports `Hypervisor vendor` and `Virtualization type`.

Answer (score 2):

Debian comes with this small package for detecting virtualisation type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virt-what
$ virt-what
```

and little bigger because of Perl dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install imvirt
$ imvirt
```

As usual run:

```
free
cat /proc/meminfo
cat /proc/cpuinfo
dmesg
htop
lshw
dmidecode
lsmod
hwinfo
```

Comment: You beat me to imvirt, and I did not known virt-what. would you detail the output of both as previous answers to improve your post?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently virtualization comes in several parts - in my case QEMU, Bochs and KVM (then Ubuntu 14.04). I found the easiest way to discover the hypervisor in use was:

```
sudo apt-get install virt-what
sudo virt-what
```

which in my case returned simply `kvm` which was the basic information I was looking for (also the OP I think), because it tells me what I am allowed to do (e.g. run ipset to block a DDoS attack) and how resources are shared between VMs.

In addition I tried

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
```

and

```
sudo lshw -class system
```

neither of which mention KVM but they did both inform me that my hardware emulation was provided by `Bochs` which I confess I hadn't even heard of, but a quick search turned up interesting information (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochs). The lshw command is slightly more informative than dmidecode (e.g. telling me it's 64-bit).

The other answers didn't really tell me anything useful - `facter virtual` just returned `physical` and `ls -1 /dev/disk/by-id/` returned `ata-QEMU_DVD-ROM_QM00003` which shows QEMU is involved but I don't have access to the emulated DVD-ROM anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Example, how is this solved in [linux-test-project](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/lib/tst_virt.c).
It might be useful for those who needs this in C code, ideally without much much of dependencies.

- first it tries external dependency `systemd-detect-virt`
- then, XEN is detected via `/proc/xen` or `/sys/hypervisor/type`,
- for KVM it checks `"QEMU Virtual CPU"` in `/proc/cpuinfo` with note, that it doesn't work with custom `-cpu` values, since there's no easy, reasonable or reliable way to work around those.

=> most of the work is done with `systemd-detect-virt`. [src/detect-virt/detect-virt.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/basic/virt.c) shows how to detect other virtualization technologies.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the file `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/sys_vendor` - it should have a relevant value that is either a real hardware vendor - for example, on my laptop it says "`Dell Inc.`" - or a virtual hardware vendor that you can identify - for example, it might say "`Amazon EC2`" or "`QEMU`" (under KVM).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is from the Linux kernel perspective.

If you know how to use crash utility, try the following:

## In a 4.4 linux kernel dump

```
crash> p x86_hyper
x86_hyper = $4 = (const struct hypervisor_x86 *) 0xffffffff81b166e0 <x86_hyper_kvm>
```

## On my kernel 5.12 laptop

```
crash> p x86_hyper_type      
x86_hyper_type = $1 = X86_HYPER_NATIVE
```

For your system, you need to read codes related to detect_hypervisor_vendor().