# Check if Ubuntu is being installed in VirtualBox VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to automate the installation of Ubuntu from a network repository. I am now successfully able to configure the ISO image and it does the installation automatically.

**My requirement:**

I would like to know if there is a method in the initial installation stage of Ubuntu, where I can tell if the OS is being installed in VirtualBox or a physical desktop. I want this check to be performed as I want to automate the installation of the VirtualBox guest additions if the installation is being performed in VirtualBox.

How can I do this?

Comment: See also [Easy way to determine virtualization technology](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89714/easy-way-to-determine-virtualization-technology)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only checking for VirtualBox and don't need to cater for all hypervisors, there's a quick and dirty way - check for the presence of VirtualBox devices.

```
lshw | grep VirtualBox
lspci | grep VirtualBox
```

I'm not sure if you'll have either or both of `lshw` and `lspci` but you can always install them as part of your custom installation (or, check the contents of `/proc/pci` instead of using `lspci`).

Comment: Or just `dmesg | grep VirtualBox`.