# why hostnamectl shows virtualization regardless no guest additions installed?

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm running a very basic debian 9 OS inside Virtualbox, I haven't installed any paravirtualization | guest additions, regardless that I get `Virtualization: oracle`. Why? isn't it supposed the OS should not be aware if it's running on real or virtual hardware?

Comment: "isn't it supposed the OS should not be aware if it's running on real or virtual hardware?" Why shouldn't it be aware?

Comment: @muru because I just installed the OS and nothing else

Comment: Ok, so? That doesn't answer why the OS shouldn't be aware of what it's running on.

Comment: How would the guest additions ever know that it was running in VirtualBox? Any program can determine this the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Detecting most actual virtualization solutions is not exactly difficult.

The Linux kernel can detect at least VMware, HyperV, Xen and KVM: look for a message like `Hypervisor detected: <virtualization type>` in `dmesg` output.

At least VMware and HyperV can be detected with the signature information they add into the results of the `cpuid` processor opcode, so they can be detected at a very low level. Looking at the outputs of `dmidecode` and/or `lspci` is another quick way to detect many forms of virtualization.

For practical reasons, most virtualization solutions present a set of system components to the VM that are known to be simple and well-supported. This often leads to combinations that would not make sense in actual physical hardware: for example, if you see an Intel ICH8M SATA controller and a Intel PIIX3 ISA bridge on the same system, that's a pretty dead giveaway: both of those are supposed to be devices integrated into the system chipset, but *they belong to very different chipsets* so they would never both exist on the same physical system.

Also, if you see parts belonging to a system chipset that were used with the original Pentium II chips with clockspeeds measured in two-digit MHz values, and yet the processor claims a multi-GHz speed, you know there has to be some virtualization going on.

See also: [Easy way to determine virtualization technology](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89714/258991)

`systemd` includes features designed for controlling VMs and containers, so its main library probably also includes a set of virtualization detection routines. You can also use them with [systemd-detect-virt command.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-detect-virt.html)